# Linking an String variable into an IP in batch

Tags: list, variables, batch-file, ping

I would like to know if I can create a list where I have a number of IPs, each is associated with a name. e.g. server1 = 10.40.90.1, server2 = 10.20.10.1, etc.

This way when I execute the file, it asks me to put in the server name, for `ping`ing, instead of the IP. Then output only the name, and percentage of packets lost.

I know how to create a list, and use it, in a batch file, but I'm not sure how to make the IP's into variables.

Comment: This would be trivial in a scripting language like Python or Perl.  Are these systems not in your DNS?  `ping` is perfectly happy to use a hostname instead of an IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are kind of under-powered for this kind of thing so the techniques are often strange.  But, you can use `set` after `setlocal` to set local variables for the servers' IP addresses.  Then you can assign the address to the IP address associated with the provided server name using `call set` and the triple `%%%` syntax to replace the provided server name with the value of the variable it refers to.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "server1=10.40.90.1"
set "server2=10.20.10.1"

set /p "server_name=Enter the server name: "
call set "ip_address=%%%server_name%%%"
echo %ip_address%

REM TODO: ping %ip_address% and parse output

endlocal
```